# Adapter fetches and parses RSS feed to get its data - best practice?

Tags: android

In a shared project, we have an Adapter class (extends BaseAdapter, implements ListAdapter).  In its constructor, this class fetches an RSS feed from the internet and parses the returned XML document to obtain the data it will 'adapt'; the data is kept in a private class variable.

This is seen as the "Android way" of doing things by the author and is supported by the project lead.
Can this be considered a "Best Practice"?
Can it be justified on the grounds that it (may?) increase performance?
Doesn't it violate the general Object Oriented Design (OOD) principle that a class should have only a "Single Responsiblity"?
Are best practices for OOD or Java to be set aside in Android development?

Comment: OO Principles are there to keep them in mind, but also to violate them. The one which is actually more important, and which most of the cases goes against others is the KISS principle (well, it's a general programming principle). Apply principles when necessary, but keep in mind simplicity...

Comment: So which would you consider the best embodiment of KISS: 1 class that both fetch/parses data AND manages it for the View _or_ 2 classes, one that does the fetch/parse only and another that does the bridge between the data and View only?

Answer (score 0):

You must use an AsyncTask for downloading the feed in the background and have it update the UI in the postExecute step.

You can google for efficient implementation of listadapter which talks about layout inflation and other things.

There are several good talks on Google I/O page if you are interested in general know how about Android's best practices.